# How to run MSTest with custom assembly path using command-line

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

MSTest uses in CI environment to run set of unit tests. These set of unit test need custom binaries to run. I'm not sure how can pass the custom assembly path to the MSTest.exe when I run the unit test using command line for debugging purpose. When it runs via TFS there is a place to configure custom assembly path in build controller as this image.

So, how to run MSTest with custom assembly path using command-line

[image]